# Nested React Component Re-rendering and React Reconcilliation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reconciliation

I'm struggling with understanding how reconciliation works when dealing with nested react components. Below is my code for index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted List")

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted List")
    }
  }, [])

  const Todo = ({ txt }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("mounted Todo")

      return () => {
        console.log("unmounted Todo")
      }
    }, [])

    return (
      <li>
        {txt}
      </li>
    );
  };
  return todos.map(todo => <Todo {...todo} />);
};

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setIt] = useState([{ txt: "foo" }, { txt: "bar" }, { txt: "baz" }])
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIt(todos.concat({ txt: 'new' }))}>Click</button>
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
    </>)
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Below is index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

The part that's confusing me is why all of the  react instances keep on un-mounting and re-mounting every time I click the button. My understanding is that the "type" of the react instances aren't the same because we define the Todo component **locally scoped** inside of the TodoList component. Due to this, we are basically creating a new Todo component every-time during re-render. However, I feel that my explanation is a very high-level answer (Also, I'm not even sure if I'm correct) and I'm unsure of the lower-level implementation details on how the react reconciler manages distinctions between the "type" of react instances when we have nested vs un-nested components. (I'm using the term "nested" and "un-nested" as meaning defining a react component inside of the another react component like in the example I gave).

Comment: You are correct. Try moving the `Todo` outside and it will work. Read [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). The first thing that it checks is the "type" of the element. Since your `Todo` is a different component each time (*since it is redefined*) it will be of different type and will require a tear-down and re-build of the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo component is unmounted because TodoList rerenders when state is changed.
If you keep you Todo component outside of the TodoList component it will not unmount once state changes.